# 12 hidden clues in just one paragraph!

Tags: word, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, steganography

I have attempted to hide as much information as I can within as little words as possible, while it still makes sense. And while the following paragraph does indeed make sense, that doesn't mean it's easy to read...

This took a very long time to work out, but the following paragraph contains 12 clues, all hidden in different ways:

[image]

Text version:

> c<sup>l</sup>u*e*s <strike>h</strike>id<sub>d</sub>en **s**<sup>e</sup>cretly wi<sup>t</sup>hin <sup>t</sup>h<sub>i</sub>s text. only som**e** peopl<sup>e</sup> cAn ad***v***anc<strike>e</strike> towa<sup>r</sup>d<sup>s</sup> th*e* <sup>an</sup>swer, en<sup>d</sup>ure thei*r* exception<sub>a</sub>l logic. no<sup>w</sup> onl*y* y<sup>o</sup>u mi<sub>g</sub>ht g**e**t the co<strike>r</strike>rect answe<sup>r</sup> here. try to solve this, i*F* y<sub>o</sub>u i**n**stantly *i*denti*f*y The appr<strike>o</strike>pria*t*e interpretation, incre<sup>d</sup>i**b**le work - i will clap. a<sup>s</sup> peo<sup>p</sup>le approach a un<strike>i</strike>qu<sup>e</sup> answe<sup>r</sup> it will bEcome clear what i<sup>s</sup> <sub>n</sub>e<sup>e</sup>ded i<sup>n</sup>volving solving steps. i hope eveR**y**bod*y* h<sub>a</sub>s won. no U**s**e in wai*t*ing for <sup>t</sup>h**e** <strike>c</strike>orr<sup>e</sup>ct ans*w*er t*o* ha**v**e see<sup>n</sup> som**e**body e<sub>*l*</sub>s*e*, 'i**n**ve<strike>s</strike>tiga*t*e *t*hes*e* wo*r*d*s*!', besee<sup>c</sup>h<sup>e</sup>s i.

<sub>(I have provided both an image and text, each make some things clearer than the other, and there may be minor differences but the answer(s) remain unchanged)</sub>

These clues will lead to you to a set of words, which combined with instructions from other clues, will give you the final answer. The final answer is a single word that describes the above puzzle.

The only other thing you need for this puzzle is the knowledge that all punctuation should be ignored.

## Can you find all the clues and the final word?

---

For those interested, this is not needed but the text itself says:

> Clues hidden secretly within this text. Only some people can advance towards the answer, endure their exceptional logic. Now only you might get the correct answer here. Try to solve this, if you instantly identify the appropriate interpretation, incredible work - I will clap. As people approach a unique answer it will become clear what is needed involving solving steps. I hope everybody has won. No use in waiting for the correct answer to have seen somebody else, 'investigate these words!', beseeches I.

Comment: I apologise in advance to anyone who dares to click 'edit' :P

Comment: **S**om**e** pu**n**c**t**uations ar**e** **n**ot **c**luel**e**s**s**.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Three extractions give instructions to be used in the next part.

> The italics spell `EVERY FIFTY TWO LETTERS`.
>  The superscript letters spell `LETTERS AND WORDS PER SENTENCE`.
>  The capital letters spell `AFTER U`.

Seven extractions give seven-letter words.

> The sentences' first letters spell `CONTAIN`.
>  Taking every 52nd letter spells `DOODLES`.
>  The letters after U spell `ERMINES`.
>  The numbers of words per sentence spell `FLIPPER` (with A=1, B=2...).
>  The numbers of letters per sentence, mod 26, spell `GOLIATH` (with A=1, B=2...).
>  The struck-through letters spell `HEROICS`.
>  The last letters of the sentences, in reverse, spell `INSPECT`.

And two more extractions give clues to getting the final answer:

> The bold letters spell `SEVEN BY SEVEN`.
>  The subscript letters spell `DIAGONAL`.

So:

> We make a 7×7 square out of our words -- which conveniently start with "CDEFGHI" -- and read the diagonal:
>  `C̲ONTAIN`
>  `DO̲ODLES`
>  `ERM̲INES`
>  `FLIP̲PER`
>  `GOLIA̲TH`
>  `HEROIC̲S`
>  `INSPECT̲`
>  and this gives the word **COMPACT**, an appropriate word to describe a bunch of information packed into a small space!

Comment: Ok wow I did not expect this to be solved that quick, wow! Well done! Hopefully wasn't too tedious :)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil My eyes hurt.  I don't know about you, but many letters look very nearly the same when italicized or with strikeout.  (I still can't find the strikeout 'e')

Comment: @DarrelHoffman yeah I originally wrote it all up in word, where it was a lot clearer, SE doesn't quite make it as clear. The strikeout e is definitely the hardest to see because the strike goes through part of the letter already, but it's in 'advance' - I'm not sure how deus solved this but you can see what has what if you click edit, although that may be more of an eyesore tbh :)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Might be worth doing a screenshot from Word and posting an image in addition to the text version.  Maybe not this time since it's already been solved, but if you do something like this again, perhaps.  I got about half of the clues before I gave up due to eyestrain...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I think that's a good idea, I might add that in now. Just see people who want to see how it was solved can see it a bit better

Comment: @DarrelHoffman added. Some things are clearer, some things less so, and some unchanged. I added a transcript as well in case anyone actually wants to read the text.